# React Native - Axios POST with urlencoded params

Tags: react-native, post, parameters, axios, urlencode

I successfully triggered POST request via Postman to retrieve mobileSession key. But when I tried the same from React Native app (via Axios), I get error that some params are missing. Can someone tell me what is wrong in Axios according to Postman request which is working?

Postman:

[image]

And Axios code:

```js
export function getMobileSession() {
    let requestOptions = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    let body = {
        username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypw',
        api_key: 'apikey',
        api_sig: 'signature',
        method: 'auth.getMobileSession',
        format: 'json'
    };

    return axios.post('Lastfm_API_URL', JSON.stringify(body), requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  return axios.post(`https://ws/audioscrobbler.com/2.0/`, JSON.stringify(body), requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
```

For more refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to know about back tick.

Comment: Didn't work with `JSON:stringify(body)` but worked with `qs` package. 
`import qs from 'qs'`   &&    `qs.stringify(body)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. In this way you will get the proper data in response.

```
postUrlEncodedData = (data: { payload: any; endPoint: string; withCredentials?: boolean }) => {
    const authorization = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + `${tokenFromLocal}` };
    const formDataEncoded = Object.keys(data.payload)
      .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + JSON.stringify(data.payload[key]))
      .join('&');
    return axios.post(data.endPoint, formDataEncoded, {
      timeout: 3000000,
      baseURL: BaseUrl,
      headers: Object.assign(
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        HeaderConfig,
        authorization
      )
    });
  };
```